# CsvHelper Map null objects but keep nullable property defaults

Tags: c#, .net, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to map a class with CsvHelper which contains a nullable int property `int?` which I'd like to map to `N/A` in the csv and in cases where a `Player` does not have a `Skill` initialized I'd like it to create a new object and use the default value set `1` but instead it looks like its using `default(int?)` so I'm getting null/empty strings being shown in the csv.

How can I map a specific value when a given condition is true i.e `!level.hasValue` for a property and how can I force it to initialize the object and use their defaults when its null instead of using `default(int?)` to resolve null properties?

```
public class Player
{
    // other properties

    public class Skill
    {
        public int? Level { get; set; } = 1;
    }
}
```

To further clarify, there will be a list of `Player` where some players have a null `Level` and in these cases I want to show `N/A` and then the other cases is Players who don't have a `Skill` initialized and in these cases I want to show the default value `1` - this however looks like its getting initialzied to `default(int?)` and its showing as empty string or null in the csv instead of `1`

Mapping:

```
Map(_ => _.Level).Name("Player Level");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your request correctly, I believe the only way to accomplish this is to use `Convert`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Player>
    {
        new Player() { Id = 1 },
        new Player() { Id = 2, Skill = new Skill()},
        new Player() { Id = 3, Skill = new Skill(){ Level = 4 }},
    };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<PlayerMap>();
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class PlayerMap : ClassMap<Player>
{
    PlayerMap()
    {
        Map(o => o.Id);
        Map(o => o.Skill.Level).Convert(o =>
        {
            if (o.Value.Skill == null)
                return "1";
                
            if (o.Value.Skill.Level == null)
                return "N/A";
                
            return o.Value.Skill.Level.ToString();
        });     
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int? Level { get; set; }
}
```